# Best practice to get user's idToken from Firebase - using getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true) leads to Firebase: Error (auth/quota-exceeded)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm working on a dashboard website in `react.js` where the users can analyze multiple different charts. To get the data for the charts from my `node.js` server I need to get the user's ID token to be able to verify it on the server side (return data only if user is authorized).

In the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) it is shown how to get the current id token:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

In my case, this leads to a `Firebase: Error (auth/quota-exceeded)` in case the user switches between different charts too frequently or refreshed the page too often.

When I don't follow the documentation and do not use `/* forceRefresh */ true` the error disappears but it might happen that the idToken is expired. Do I always force the idToken to refresh for each API call like shown in the documentation? If not: How where and when do I check if the token is already expired?
What is the best practice to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken), in your case you don't need to pass `/* forceRefresh */ true`:

> `getIdToken` returns the current token if it has not expired. Otherwise, this will
> refresh the token and return a new one.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken

Comment: Great thanks, Renaud. I don't understand why they put it in their example then ..

Comment: @smaica Fair point. If you want to leave feedback on the Firebase documentation, there's a `Send feedback` link at the bottom of each page to do so.

Comment: Does setting the `forceRefresh` param as `true` effectively mean that an ID token is single-use?